# Regex to match all spaces, except single spaces having words on both sides

Tags: javascript, regex

I have come so far:

1) Run regex `/ /g` to match all spaces.

2) Run a new call to regex `/\b( )\b/g` to match the spaces that need to be excluded.

Now I need them both fused in one statement. All spaces except the ones returned by the second. Any help?

Live regex for testing: https://regex101.com/r/26w2WR/1

**EDIT:** Although good answers are already available, I found that trying to match "words" with `\b` or `\B` is not always a good idea, as a lot of printable characters like dots and quotes are not seen as words by RegEx. Another problem is when you are looping through DOM nodes, sometimes you encounter inline styling tags like `<strong>` which should also just count as a beginning/end of a word, but a **#text** node just ends before the tag. So you may want to include start & end of a string in the RegEx too. For anyone wishing to address these too, I ended up with this RegEx:

```
/(\S|^)( )(?=\S|$)/g
```

This uses `\S` (not white space), inlcudes start/end of a string and applies groups for replacement ability. Replace JS looks like this:

```
yourTextNode.replace(/(\S|^)( )(?=\S|$)/g, '$1'+ yourreplacement)
```

To match `&nbsp;` chars, you can use `(\u00A0)` instead of  `( )`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean [`(?!\b \b)( )`](https://regex101.com/r/26w2WR/2)?

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any look-around you can use this regex with `\B` and alternation:

```
\B +| +\B
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/26w2WR/3)

`\B` assert position where \b does not match

Above matches a space that is preceded or followed by `\B`

Comment: Thanks for another approach. How is this performance wise, compared to negative look-ahead?

Comment: This is definitely faster than using a lookahead. You can select FLAVOR as php on regex101 site and see no of steps taken to execute. This one takes less steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative look-ahead:

[`(?!\b \b)( )`](https://regex101.com/r/26w2WR/2)